# A clock has identical rectangular hands for hrs and mins. What is the expected overlapping area between them over an hr?

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Ok, so it's not the problem I'm *really* interested in, but it's almost the same and I thought it can be posed as a more interesting question. What I'm actually looking for is the expected area between two identical, finite, but very long and very thin strips which intersect at a random angle. For simplicity, assume that the point of intersection is halfway through their length.

[A descriptive image, but with different notation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCSlQ.png) The image is taken from [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.6389.pdf). I know that for infinite strips of width *w* intersecting at an angle $\theta$, the area can be estimated by $\int{ \frac{w^2}{sin\theta} d\theta}$, but the integral doesn't converge. It's easy to see that it's something between $w^2$ when perpendicular and $wL$, where *L* is the length of the strip, at full overlap.